# Check 2 same data in different table in vfp, so i can put it in an IF statement

Tags: database, visual-foxpro, foxpro

If `table_A.firstname` had the same exact data in `table_B.firstname` then a messagebox will appear.
I would like to know what is the code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
if trim(table_A.firstname) == trim(table_B.firstname)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find all duplicates in `table_B.firstname`

```
close all
set talk off

use table_a in 0
use table_b in 0

sele table_a
scat memv

do while !eof()
    sele table_b
    scan for firstname=m.firstname
        wait wind allt(m.firstname)+" RecNo="+allt(str(recno()))
    endscan
    sele table_a
    if !eof()
        skip
        scat memv
    endif
enddo
close all
```

If you want to use If.. Else... (just modify in the Do while loop)

```
do while !eof()
    sele table_b
    go top
    locate for firstname=m.firstname
    if found()
        wait wind allt(m.firstname)+" RecNo="+allt(str(recno()))
    endif
    sele table_a
    if !eof()
        skip
        scat memv
    endif
enddo
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, prefer scan ... endscan over do while ... skip.. enddo loops (you didn't need to mix them, you could use scan instead of do while). And also thinking there might be an index on firstname, using seek(...) and then scan WHILE would be a much faster approach (but anyway wait windows are there to slow things completely).

Comment: @CetinBasoz Is there a need of `Index` for `Locate` command? (doubt)

Comment: Locate, seek, scan for\while, select, browse for\while ... whatever does a 'locate' utilizes indexes if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said same data in two tables, you need to compare each and every field from one source record with target all every records with against their each respective field in it.
(Assuming both tables data structure is identical in all aspects)

```
CLOSE ALL  
CLEAR ALL  
RELEASE ALL  

SET TALK OFF  

SELECT 1
USE file1
GO TOP

SELECT 2
USE file2

DO WHILE NOT EOF()

    SELECT 1

    unq_found = 0

    SELECT 2
    GO TOP

    DO WHILE NOT EOF()

        SELECT 2

        for ix = 1 to AFIELDS(TEST)

            SRC_FLD = "A." + ALLTRIM(FIELD(IX))
            TRG_FLD = "B." + ALLTRIM(FIELD(IX))

            IF ALLTRIM(&SRC_FLD) <> ALLTRIM(&TRG_FLD)
                unq_found = 1
                EXIT for
            ENDIF

        ENDFOR

        IF unq_found = 0

            @00,00 CLEAR
            @10,10 SAY "SAME DATA:- " 
            @12,10 SAY "RECORD NUMBER:-" + STR ( RECNO() ) 
            @18,10 SAY "PRESS A KEY TO CONTINUE"
            READ

        ENDIF

        SKIP

    ENDDO


    SELECT 1
    skip

ENDDO
```

Comment: Why would you ever need to use macro substitution there? Select 1, select 2, A. B. ...? That is a dangerous way of using aliases and workareas. Simply use the table aliases. For comparison you don't need to do it field by field. There is at least 2 simple ways, 1) Scattering to and comparing objects 2) Comparing row level checksums. Although tagged Foxpro I don't think he is really using FP DOS.

Comment: @CetinBasoz :- Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions and tips. I would certainly try to explore on it too.